# Keyboard shortcuts in an AppleScript list dialog

Tags: dialog, applescript, keyboard-shortcuts

I am looking for a way to assign keyboard shortcuts to the items in a list dialog in AppleScript.

I am using the following to display a long list of folder names and am looking for an easy way to select an item from the list.

```
set selectedFolderName to {choose from list folderList}
```

Currently the list displays like :

```
Office
Personal
Projects
... 
Vendors
```

and I have to navigate down the list with the cursor keys or mouse to select an item.  I would like to be able to show either :

```
a) Office
b) Personal
c) Projects
... 
m) Vendors
```

or :

```
Office
Personal
pRojects
... 
Vendors
```

Then I could press the <kbd>C</kbd> key (first example) or <kbd>R</kbd> key (second example) to select 'Projects'.

I studied the AppleScript documentation, such as it is, and searched far and wide, but have not been able to spot a way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally sure if this is what you want, but I use the construct below, so that I can press "a", to select the first item, "b" to select the second item, and so on.

```
set litems to {"apples", "pears", "banana", "oranges", "plums", "grapes"}

set deli to "." & space & space
repeat with i from 1 to (count litems)
    set item i of litems to character id (i + 96) & deli & item i of litems
end repeat
log litems
set theRes to choose from list litems
(*a.  apples, b.  pears, c.  banana, d.  oranges, e.  plums, f.  grapes*)
set origItem to text 5 thru -1 of item 1 of theRes
log origItem
—> plums
```

Answer (score 0):

The second version of what you're asking is not possible. But, the first is. There is nothing built in for this kind of functionality, but you can build your own sub-routine for it. You can prepend your list items with letters or numbers (I'll use numbers since it's simpler).

```
on choose_from_list_with_shortcut(ls)
    -- prepend the choices with "1) "
    repeat with i from 1 to (count ls)
        set item i of ls to (i as string) & ") " & item i of ls
    end repeat

    set chosenItems to choose from list ls

    -- strip the prefixes from the chosen items
    repeat with i from 1 to (count chosenItems)
        set item i of chosenItems to text 4 thru -1 of item i of chosenItems
    end repeat

    return chosenItems
end choose_from_list_with_shortcut
```

Another option is to just start typing. Just like in the Finder, if you type the letters "pro," the list will highlight "Projects."