# Enabling keyboard shortcuts to confirm Dialogs in AppleScript

Tags: dialog, applescript, keyboard-shortcuts, interaction

I am looking for a way to allow a user to complete a Dialog entry using keyboard shortcuts. Is this possible?

[Other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28305780/keyboard-shortcuts-in-an-applescript-list-dialog) have discussed assigning shortcuts to the *options* in an AppleScript dialog box, but not to the "Continue"/"Okay" etc. button.

The main difficulty is that I'm using a multi-line text entry form, so the <kbd>Enter</kbd> button simply creates a new line, instead of targeting the default button as it would conventionally. I'm hoping <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> can be assigned to the default button instead.

The line of script defining the dialog in question is:

```
set theResponse to display dialog "Enter tasks:" default answer "





" buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button "Continue"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your **AppleScript** *code* from **Script Editor** on a *US English* **MacBook Pro**, whether or not something is typed in, <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> *presses* the <kbd>Continue</kbd> button.

The same *keyboard shortcut* works on an *US English* **Apple Magic Keyboard** when connected to the **MacBook Pro** and I'd assume any *US English* **Mac** it was connected to would do the same. I only have the **MacBook Pro** to test with at the moment.

---

In **macOS**, by default, pressing the <kbd>tab</kbd> *key* in this use case **will not move between the *controls*** as the controlling setting in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** is not set to allow it to act on all *controls*.

**You must select one of the following options, depending on the version of macOS one is running, in order to use the <kbd>tab</kbd> *key* on all *controls*.**

***If you see:***

**Full Keyboard Access: In windows and dialogs, press Tab to move keyboard focus between:**

**(•) Text boxed and lists only**
    **( ) All Controls**

*Select:* **(•) All Controls**

***If you see:***

**[] Use keyboard navigation to move between controls**
    <sup>**Press the Tab key to move focus forward and Shift Tab to move focus backward.**</sup>

*Check:* **[√] Use keyboard navigation to move between controls**

**With this done, one can then use <kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> to press the <kbd>continue</kbd> *button*, with the dialog box produced by the *code* shown in the OP.**

---

**Side Note:** One can also try <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> as that was necessary from within a VMware **macOS Catalina** virtual machine that I also tested in.

Comment: How odd. `fn` + `enter` does not work, at least when the text input is multi-line. It still only adds a new line. However, the `tab` full control workaround is clever. I knew that existed but failed to think of it here. Thanks!

Comment: @ryanjamurphy, `fn+enter` and `fn+command+enter` does indeed work on my MBP using your **AppleScript** _code_, which produces a multi-line text field dialog box. It may have to do with using a US English keyboard and layout and maybe even the version of **macOS**, which is **macOS High Sierra** on the system I tested and also **macOS Catalina** in a VMware virtual machine. The `tab`+`tab`+`enter` worked only after changing the default settings as mentioned in my answer. Anyway, I'm glad the information I've provided was helpful to you, thanks.

Comment: @ryanjamurphy,  What version of **macOS** and keyboard and layout are you using?

Comment: macOS Catalina, and I tried both Canadian English (my default) and US English. Perhaps it's the external keyboard I'm using. Oh well—the full keyboard control works just fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>⌘-Enter</kbd> (on the numeric keypad) *presses* `Continue`

Comment: Thanks—is this true on a multi-line input though? I don't have a numeric keyboard to test this out, sadly.

Comment: @ryanjamurphy - On some apple keyboards the `⌘` + `↵` key combination is essentially the same as `⌘` + `return`. Toggling through the various languages for keyboards [here](https://www.apple.com/uk/shop/product/MLA22B/A/magic-keyboard-british-english) the notable difference seems to be _"US English"_ which denotes the  `↵` key with the word `return`. Both `↵` and `return` are what applescript identifies as [keycode 36](https://eastmanreference.com/complete-list-of-applescript-key-codes#return-and-enter).

Comment: Thanks, @RobC. Interesting. I switched my keyboard language from Canadian English to U.S., but the `Enter` key still returns `↵` according to [Keycastr](https://github.com/keycastr/keycastr).

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a multiline text field, hit the `Tab` key so that focus is on some element other than the text field. Then the `Enter` key should route properly to the dialog's default close button.

Comment: Yes, but this does not work in a multi-line input field in an AppleScript Dialog box.

Comment: I tested it with the code you gave , and it *does* work.

Comment: Odd. It must be the external keyboard I'm using, somehow.

Comment: I just tested it with a different app (Safari) and a different keyboard, to no avail. Hrm.

Comment: Hm. It may be a setting on my machine, or something app dependent.  weird.